# Using god to monitor unicorn; "god log unicorn" gets stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, god

I am on CentOS 6.5 and running god to monitor unicorn which is being used with nginx to deploy a ruby on rails application.  I am able to start god and unicorn without issue but when I run the command

```
god log unicorn
```

I get the "Please wait..." message but nothing happens after that.  I've waited for about an hour without anything happening.  Does anyone know what would cause this?  I tried searching it in google and got absolutely nothing.  My files for god configuration are taken directly from http://www.synbioz.com/blog/monitoring_server_processes_with_god.  I got to the part that tells you to try god log unicorn.  Here is the unicorn.god file I have based on the one in that link.  It's slightly different.

```
rails_root = File.dirname("/home/username/myApp")

God.watch do |w|
  pid_file = File.join(rails_root, "myApp/pids/unicorn.pid")

  w.name = "unicorn"
  w.interval = 60.seconds
  w.start = "unicorn -c #{rails_root}/myApp/config/unicorn.rb -D"
  w.stop = "kill -s QUIT $(cat #{pid_file})"
  w.restart = "kill -s HUP $(cat #{pid_file})"
  w.start_grace = 20.seconds
  w.restart_grace = 20.seconds
  w.pid_file = pid_file

  w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)

  # When to start?
  w.start_if do |start|
    start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      # We want to check if deamon is running every ten seconds
      # and start it if itsn't running
      c.interval = 10.seconds
      c.running = false
    end
  end

  # When to restart a running deamon?
  w.restart_if do |restart|
    restart.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
      # Pick five memory usage at different times
      # if three of them are above memory limit (100Mb)
      # then we restart the deamon
      c.above = 100.megabytes
      c.times = [3, 5]
    end

    restart.condition(:cpu_usage) do |c|
      # Restart deamon if cpu usage goes
      # above 90% at least five times
      c.above = 90.percent
      c.times = 5
    end
  end

  w.lifecycle do |on|
    # Handle edge cases where deamon
    # can't start for some reason
    on.condition(:flapping) do |c|
      c.to_state = [:start, :restart] # If God tries to start or restart
      c.times = 5                     # five times
      c.within = 5.minute             # within five minutes
      c.transition = :unmonitored     # we want to stop monitoring
      c.retry_in = 10.minutes         # for 10 minutes and monitor again
      c.retry_times = 5               # we'll loop over this five times
      c.retry_within = 2.hours        # and give up if flapping occured five times in two hours
    end
  end
end
```